# jQuery pretty select elements - dropkick js and iOs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, jquery-dropkick

Hello I have implemented Dropkick.js on to my site and now have some very very good looking select elements. However when I look at it on a iOS system I am not able to scroll down my options.

I have read the documentation of Dropkick.js and it suggests that I try and use [scrollability.js](https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability) however I cannot for the live of work out to make this work.

Does anyone have any experience of using this and dropkick.js - or does anyone have any suggestions to alternatives?

Comment: Haha why was this downvoted? I've never worked with this before, but it seems like a fair question. Unless there's an obvious answer, but just downvoting doesn't help anyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used DropKick.js and scrollability.js together, but I can tell you from experience that DropKick doesn't have native mobile support since it was built for desktop browsers and not phones.

Since mobile phone browsers usually have their own handler for the  tag, a lot of JavaScript plugins don't have proper support for phones because their code actively removes  and replaces it with a  of their own design or doesn't even use  tags in the first place.

If you're looking to make your site work on both iOS/mobile browsers and Desktops, I recommend using SelectBox.js from [A Beautiful Site.net](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/) even though it's a little bit more difficult to style than DropKick.js.

If you're looking for a purely mobile solution, I would recommend just using pure CSS to style your  as seen [HERE](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) since it's simpler, quicker, and leaves  tags in place.

Hope this helps!